# Jsoup different results Windows & Linux

Tags: java, jsoup

I have written a function for parsing HTML from a specific URL using Jsoup(1.11.2) see code below.

I have some OS issues:

On Windows 10 it is working perfectly fine, but I won't get the full content when executing on Linux. Can someone explain why I get different results?

```
public Document getJsoup(){
    Document doc = null;
    String url = "http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/advanced.php?t=country&n[]=IT&c[]=IT&gen=50&age-min=18&age-max=50"; 

    try {
        doc =  Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36")
                .get();            
        System.out.println(url);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // error handling
    }
    return doc; 
}
```

UPDATE

OSX has the same result as Windows, only linux seems to have issues

Comment: are you using the same JDK vendor and version on Windows and Linux? If the JDKs are the same, can you test your code, but remove the explicit userAgent config? What is exactly the difference you're getting in your response in Windows and Linux?

Comment: JDKs are the same. When removing the userAgent the site will return 403, so I need a userAgent(have changed the UA multiple times same result). The HTML is quite big I won't spam stack with it, but on Windows/OSX i get the full page HTML and on Linux I do not get the generated profile(if you visited the website, you know what I mean)

Comment: I've added an update to my answer

Comment: Will test it shortly(today/tomorrow), thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to retrieve the whole page on Linux (including details/profile part) using the following code snippet:

```
try {
  Document document = Jsoup.connect(url);
  Element criteria = document.getElementById("criteria");
  Element details = document.getElementById("details"); //the profile you're talking about
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Some observations:

- I didn't specify any userAgent details
- jsoup version is 1.10.2
- JDK version is 9.0.1

**Update:**

I was able to test the code on Windows and OS X (different JDKs - 8 and 9) and it returns exactly the same results it returns in Linux.